# Function CallByName with args out of order

Tags: vb.net

I'm using callbyname in vb.net to call another function with arguments. But the arguments order is only known in runtime. So I want to define the argument by it's name, not the position in the args array.

```
Private Sub mainSub()
    Dim argArr as Object()

    ReDim Preserve argArr(1)
    argArr(0) = "argTwo:= "Argument Two""
    argArr(1) = "argOne:= "Argument One""

    callbyname(auxSub, CallType.Method, argArr)
End Sub


Private Sub auxSub(ByVal argOne as String, ByVal argTwo as String)
    MsgBox("First Argument = " & argOne)
    MsgBox("Second Argument = " & argTwo)
End Sub
```

In this example the messagebox would show the following messages:

*First Argument - argTwo:= "Argument Two"*

*Second Argument - argOne:= "Argument One"*

Instead of:

*First Argument - Argument One*

*Second Argument - Argument Two*

Comment: You will have to use Reflection instead.  ParameterInfo provides argument names.  The odds that you *really* want to do this ought to be low.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this in the first place?  It could be legitimate but I've seen more than one person try this sort of thing for no good reason.

Comment: The reason is that the user can create an userform with the items and order he wants to. And the form controls are the parameters of the function. I'll try to learn more about the reflection function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibly nasty way of doing this would be for your function to use a dictionary of argument names as the key and assign values from the argArr. If you're just using a one type of value e.g string values as in your example and the number of possible arguments is reasonably small, you could do it like the example below, but anything more complicated and as Hans said, you'd need to muck about with reflection.

```
Private Sub mainSub()
    Dim argArr As Object()

    ReDim Preserve argArr(1)
    argArr(0) = "argTwo:= ""Argument Two"""
    argArr(1) = "argOne:= ""Argument One"""

    auxSub(argArr)
End Sub


Private Sub auxSub(argArray() As String)
    'define a dictionary of arguments and add valid argument names
    Dim ArgumentList As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    ArgumentList.Add("argOne", "")
    ArgumentList.Add("argTwo", "")
    'Iterate through the argument array and assign the appropriate value to its matching dictionary key 
    For Each arg As String In argArray
        ArgumentList(Split(arg, " := ")(0)) = Split(arg, " := ")(1)
    Next

End Sub
```

You would of course need more code to check that the argument names are valid of course.